# Removing " from multiple files

Tags: replace

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.  I have a number of files that are now named:

```
““““ALF16S21.SpaceSaver9.ITS.CTTCAATAA.CATTACGCCA.plant.ALF.R1.fq”A”””
““““ALF16S21.*.*.*.*.plant.ALF.R*.fq”A”””
```

I need to remove all the extraneous characters to create:

```
ALF16S21.SpaceSaver9.ITS.CTTCAATAA.CATTACGCCA.plant.ALF.R1.fq
ALF16S21.*.*.*.*.plant.ALF.R*.fq
```

`for f in *; do mv -i "$f" “${f//[\”\]}”; done`

just adds another `" .`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those double-quotes you want to remove are not ASCII quotes, they're Unicode punctuation (I'm guessing you're using macOS?). You'll need a different pattern to match those.

Comment: Are those asterisks? How on earth are they part of a filename?

Comment: The asterisks are denoting the pattern.  They are not actually there.  They are wildcards denoting a pattern.
I am on a linux super computer.  The mapping file was generated on a Mac though.

Comment: Dai, Thanks.  That helped.  I was not able to fix that exact issue, but I was able to go a few steps back to where the mess started and fix that so the issue never appeared because of your comment.